# Nginx redirect www domain to non-www

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect, certbot

I want [www.example.app](http://www.example.app) to go to example.app for SEO, and I followed several tutorials and problem solutions but can't seem to get it working.

I added a separate server block that redirects to the non-www domain and restarted nginx several times, also accessing my site from an incognito window.

Here is my  `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
configuration file.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
server {
    server_name www.example.app;
    return 301 $scheme://example.app$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    root /var/www/html/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name exampe.app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }

        location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 /customerror_404.html;
    location = /customerror_404.html {
        root /usr/shar/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
    
}


server {
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.app; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = example.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in my config:

```
if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
  set $host_without_www $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I use this to redirect from www domain to non-www domain.

You need to tell nginx if what host you want to redirect from in this case from www.

If this does not work. You may need to set server name to be like this

```
server_name www.example.app example.app;
```

So the host is recognized.

Comment: Tried it out, by adding your block of code at the end. I also changed ```server_name``` to what you suggested, but no luck. Still not working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  Is port 80 open on your server?

Comment: Yeah, port is open.

Comment: I am going to try to replicate your scenario and get back to you.